# Is it possible to pass on Event exclusive moves through breeding?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-sixth-generation

Someone on a trading group offered me an 'Event Pikachu', which was a Pikachu that knows Surf (normally impossible to teach to Pikachu).

Unfortunately it was a previous Generation's Event, and as such doesn't count as a 'Kalos-Born' Pokemon for tournaments/rating battles and the like.

So assuming I got a hold of it, could I breed this Pikachu to get a Kalos-born Pikachu with Surf?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't, but I'll let someone answer who knows for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to get Surfing or Flying Pikachu in Generation 6 games, because Pokémon that know HM moves cannot pass through transfer systems.

Consequently, if someone is offering you such a Pikachu in X and Y, you can be pretty sure it's hacked - at least, until an event is run distributing it!

EDIT: Upon a little more investigation, even if a Surfing Pikachu event is released, breeding it will NOT give another Surfing Pikachu, because Pikachu is not compatible with the Surf HM and it therefore will not be passed down - only TMs that can be learned by the child (in this case, Pichu or Pikachu as the case may be) are passed.

Comment: Have you actually tried breeding one or is this based on egg moves lists?

Comment: I have bred my Surfing Pikachu in Platinum, and the child did not have Surf.