# Is it possible to bred event moves onto a Pokemon's offspring

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

The main ones I had in mind were Tickle Wobbuffet and Sludge Wave Gengar

Comment: While this is similar, surfing Pikachu is different as HMs behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem so. [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_breeding#Passing_moves_down) states this:

> The moves obtained by a Pokémon when hatching are as follows:
>
> - By default, the baby Pokémon will start with any moves that it learns at level 1. (In Generation II and Generation III, they knew all moves that are level 5 and below in their learnset.)
> - If both parents know a move that the baby can learn via leveling up, the Pokémon will inherit that move.
> - Prior to Generation VI, if the father knows any TM or HM moves (and in Crystal, Move Tutor moves) that the baby is also compatible with, it will inherit the move. If a genderless Pokémon breeds with Ditto, the resultant baby will inherit any compatible TM or HM moves that the genderless non-Ditto Pokémon parent knows.
> - If the father or (starting in Generation VI) the mother knows any specific Egg moves that the baby can learn, the baby will inherit the move. If the parents both know different Egg moves, the mother's Egg moves are passed on first, then followed by the father's.
> - From Pokémon Emerald onward, for a baby Pichu, if either parent is holding a Light Ball, the Pichu will know Volt Tackle. Volt Tackle cannot be passed down as a normal Egg move.

Moves from events won't fulfill any of these criteria because they won't normally be available to be learnt on that Pokémon, so they cannot be passed on via breeding.
See also: [Is it possible to pass on Event exclusive moves through breeding?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158761/is-it-possible-to-pass-on-event-exclusive-moves-through-breeding).